# Converting 2d js arrays to go (golang) slice of struct in webassembly takes too much time

Tags: go, webassembly

Good time of day to all of you!
I have an 2d array which consists of a couple of thousand points like `[[x, y, some_data],[x, y, some_data],[x, y, some_data]...[x, y, some_data]]`
I have an algorithm which is processing all of those points. I want to speed it up using golang, because this algorithm can be run hundred of times by user with different sets of points.
In order to process those values in go I'm sending this 2d array to go, receive it ad an []interface{} and then converting it to slice of Points (struct):

```
type Point struct {
    x         float64
    y         float64
    some_data float64
}
```

```
func I2PointArray(src js.Value) []Point {
    srcLen := src.Length()
    dst := make([]Point, srcLen)
    for i := 0; i < srcLen; i++ {
        x := src.Index(i).Index(0).Float()
        y := src.Index(i).Index(1).Float()
        some_data := 0.0
        if !src.Index(i).Index(2).IsUndefined() {
            some_data = src.Index(i).Index(2).Float()
        }
        dst[i] = Point{x, y, some_data}
    }
    return dst
}
```

And as for the algorithm speed I got boost up to 8x , where js implementation took 16ms to proceed, golang proceeded it for 2ms

**BUT**

if js took like 9ms
Golang took around 270ms
where 268ms are wasted on converting interface to Points slice. So is there any way I can speed this conversion process?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "where 268ms are wasted on converting interface to Points slice" which part of your code is that?

Comment: @Volker executing of whole I2PointArray took 268ms

Comment: Basically there is nothing in that function you can speed up. If `Index` is slow it might help to call `Index(i)` just once instead of three times. But most likely you have to redesign and find a faster way to transmit your data than through js.Value.

Comment: @Volker using index once speeded it up to around 80 ms, using CopyBytesToGo speeded up to 25 ms but it still took longer than js. And I am creating this question in order to find a faster way by collecting answers from you and others.